# For emulating the Gameboy, why does it matter that the memory is broken up into different areas?

Tags: emulation, gameboy

So I'm writing a gameboy emulator, and I'm not 100% sure why other projects took the time to break up the memory into proper categories.  I don't know if there is a major technical dilemma I'm missing (maybe handling illegal parameters in instructions?), but it seems like the only thing that matters is that the address given by a write instruction is retrievable by the proper read instruction.  So for a sub question, if I'm working under the assumption that the assembly is perfectly legal (meaning nothing is trying to read/write where it can't), can I just make a big array and read and write to it?

Note that this is a conceptual question and that I am aware a big array would be a memory hog, I'm not necessarily looking for the best way to do it, simply trying to learn how it works and why other emulator developers did it the way they did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have read only memory, read/write memory and memory mapped I/O (peripherals etc). So you need to decode the address to some extent to break it into the major categories, then for the peripherals you have to emulate all of those so you have to get very detailed in your address decoding.

For the peripherals you will need to detect a read/write to some address which you cannot do by simply landing the writes in an array (two writes of the same value for example make a difference, you cant just scan some array to look for changes you have to trigger on reads and writes and perform the hardware action).

If you wish to be cycle accurate you will also need to know the timings for the rams and roms in order to mimic those, depending on how many banks of each or if timing is dependent on that you will need to decode the address further.

Hardware decodes these addresses to the same level so if you are emulating hardware then you need to...emulate hardware...and do the same amount of address decoding.

Comment: So to make sure I get this right, it is important to split it up because the different pieces have different timings that are crucial to it operating, right?

Comment: If you are emulating hardware you need to...emulate the hardware.   In the hardware the processor bus is going to have a hierarchy of logic that divides the address space up into ram and rom and peripherals and then within these areas may further divide it (peripherals in particular).  So when you emulate all of this in software at a minimum you have to trigger on read and write access to the peripherals to emulate what those transactions do, and you have to block writes to the read only rom/flash space.   you cant do any of this with one big read/write array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be gameboy specific here. Look at gameboy's address space map. The address space itself is divided, it's not that emulators do it. Hardware itself operates that way.

Here's some of the regions that can't be implemented as just an array:

1. 0x0000-0x3FFF. First bank of a ROM. It's read-only but not quite. Read the next one
2. 0x4000-0x7FFF. Switchable ROM bank, it's also not quite read-only. Cartridges that don't fit into gameboy's address space contain memory bank controller. ROM will write to some specific read-only ROM regions to actually select which ROM bank is mapped into 0x4000-0x7FFF address range. So you have to detect these writes and then redirect reads into the selected ROM bank.
3. 0xA000-0xBFFF. Switchable RAM bank. Same thing as with switchable ROM banks but now for RAM. Cartridges may contain additional RAM that's being mapped into gameboy's address space. Which bank of the RAM is mapped is controlled, again, by writes to specific read-only regions.
4. 0xFF00-0xFF4B. IO ports. Here you have hardware registers mapped into address space. Gameboy has several hardware components each with it's own registers and even memory (display controller, sound processor, timers etc). To control that hardware ROM reads and writes into the IO ports. You obviously have to detect these writes so you can emulate the hardware they correspond to. It's not just CPU and memory you have to emulate. I would even say that the least part of it and the easy one. For example, it much harder to get display controller and sound channels right. They have complicated logic, bugs and very tricky behaviour that's not documented very well but is crucial to achieve accurate emulation. Wave channel in particular gave me a hard time.